# Unable to auomate SWF component using Selenium

Tags: perl, selenium

I am automating test for a website using selenium, but selenium is not able to identify SWF components. Please let me know if there's a way to automate SWF components with Selenium & perl.

Here's the test link to check proof of concept:
http://demo.swfupload.org/v220/simpledemo/index.php

Comment: I tried to click button by mousedownAt and mouseupAt selenium command.

Also tried selenium commnd (IDE) click SWFUpload_0

but it does not click hello button.

Comment: flex-ui-selenium and flash-selenium also do not help me to fix the problem as I want to use it in perl.

Comment: <tr>
 <td>open</td>
 <td>/v220/simpledemo/index.php</td>
 <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>assertTextPresent</td>
 <td>Upload Queue</td>
 <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>click</td>
 <td>css=object#SWFUpload_0</td>
 <td></td>
</tr>


I tried above code and selenium IDE run all command but does not open file browser

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Rather than adding comments, you can simply click the "edit" link and modify your question directly if you need to clarify something or provide more details. Also see the editing help page: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: ok 1 - open, /v220/simpledemo/index.php
ok 2 - wait_for_page_to_load, 30000
ok 3 - is_text_present, Upload Queue
ok 4 - click, css=object\#SWFUpload_0

Comment: @user392688: edit your comments into the question.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem in automating a flash uploader widget in my own tests. Unfortunately, selenium cannot be used to automate run-of-the-mill flash SWF files.

If you want to upload something, then throw a script up on your server to which you can POST file data, and POST the data directly from your script (I am assuming that you are running selenium-rc). In any case, this is just working around the flash widget.

Answer (score 1):

There is a [Selenium-Flex API](http://code.google.com/p/sfapi/).  I believe it requires instrumenting your swf files so that their controls are actually called by JavaScript, but includes a tool for doing that instrumentation.

I have not tried this, but might when I have some time...

EDIT:

Just noticed you referenced it not working for you in comments already.  If you need to call it from perl it may indeed be impossible.  I'd have to be a real user of it to know.